Ubuntu Static Public IP not working (22.04)
We are trying to install a Machine with Ubuntu Server 22.04 in a Data Centre. The DC Host told us these public IP Addresses:

IPv4 Net: XXX.XXX.XXX.160/29
Gateway: XXX.XXX.XXX.161
(The X's are the same for IPv4 and Gateway)

So, we are not really Networking experts but following some Guides we changed the netplan Config File to:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [XXX.XXX.XXX.160/29]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: XXX.XXX.XXX.161
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true

Its still not working and we tried a loooot of things in many hours. Here some more informations and behaviours:

Our server rack has a fibre glass cable, that should connect us to the Internet. I have never seen this, but a guy in the data centre gave us a Unmanaged Media Converter T RJ45 to X SFP. Does this makes sense? Never seen such a device.
When we connect the server to the internet (via the Media Converter) the Gateway IP recieves Pings from the outside world. Also traceroutes do work.
We cannot Ping the Outside world at all. We also cant Ping the Gateway IP from the Server.
Tracerouting the IP ending with .160 does not work. It ends in an endless loop.
SSH to the Gateway IP throws us a "Connection Refused". SSH to the .160 - .167 IPs throws us a "No route to host" error.
When disconnecting the Server from the Media Converter (the Media Converter is still plugged into the Fibre Glass Cable) we still get the same SSH errors, but we cant ping the gateway anymore.
We brought a Router from home to connect a Laptop to the Server at the DC. Could this break any configs in ubuntu permanently? We also disconnected the router from the server all the time we tried a connection and also restarted the server a couple of times.
A nmap scan showed us, that the port 646 is open. Is that maybe a hint for something? Is it maybe the Media Converter?
Of course we ran "sudo netplan apply" all the time. As mentioned we also restarted the server regulary.

We don't know what the problem is. Are we missing something? Are some extra configurations in Ubuntu needed. Do we maybe need an extra device like a router or switch? Did our Data Centre Host forget to tell us an information, that could be important?
Thanks for your help

Why do you have a second ethernet interface configured with dhcp in your netplan file? I guess that's disconnected, right? What does ip route say?

we used it to connect the router temporarly with the server. It was disconnected when testing. has ip route the same output as only "route"?

@jovan You're sure that this is actually a public internet line and not a router that you have to be on?  If the 'line' for the public IP is in fact the router line then you're doing it wrong.  The datacenter may also be not giving you proper information, or you may need to adjust your CIDR mask if the gateway is outside your network range.

Crosspost from serverfault

@jovan Your team and yourself are misunderstanding how network address allocation is done, and how to interpret words form the Datacenter.  Refer to my post, I address both how to interpret their range statement, and what your config needs to be.

Not exactly the same but I crucially failed to read "IPv4 net", so I think Thomas Ward is right, you're trying to use the net address as your machine's address

The core problem is really this: You and your team don't understand what the ISP told you about network ranges and how to determine what IP addresses are actually usable by your server and network connections.  Which is really the only thing we have to address here, because then understanding this makes the answer self-explanatory.

So let's start by addressing the core problem - understanding what the ISP is telling you for your network block allocations.
The ISP (datacenter, etc.) has given you the Network Address, the CIDR range, and the Gateway IP in that range that you route through.  This is all the information you need to know to determine what IPs are or are not usable in your range. (Note that I'm using a range in my examples that NEVER exists in the Internet for the purposes of typing my examples out because Force Of Habit. 127.255.255 will be replaced by the first three octets of your actual range.)
The network address is the start of the network definition.  It is not usable.
When they say to you that your network range is 127.255.255.160/29 and the gateway is 127.255.255.161, you need to understand what this means:
Unusable Network Start IP: 127.255.255.160/29
First usable IP in block: 127.255.255.161  (Unusable by you per ISP!)
Last usable IP address in block: 127.255.255.166
Broadcast IP in block: 127.255.255.167 (also not assignable)
The ISP indicates the gateway is 127.255.255.161.  Which means you cannot use this IP.  And by default, the last IP address in a network block is the Broadcast address and also not usable in IP assignments.
This leaves you with the IP addresses between 127.255.255.162 and .165 usable.
(This information, except for the "ISP gateway address is unusable" bit can be found by using ipcalc 127.255.255.160/29 by the way)

Now for your actual server config.  NORMALLY I would suggest you put a firewall in front of anything, but if you only have one server and this is it, you'll just need to properly firewall your machine from general Internet access.
Your Netplan config however for your server connected to your Internet link needs to look like this:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  eno1:
    dhcp4: no
    addresses: [XXX.XXX.XXX.162/29]
    routes:
      - to: default
        via: XXX.XXX.XXX.161
    nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]

Omit the DHCP from your second Ethernet interface if it is connected to anything. DO NOT configure DHCP alongside static or it breaks things!
This will set your system to the first usable IP address in the network block.
Also run sudo ufw enable and enable at least a basic firewall.  Allow SSH access remotely selectively from trusted IPs and set up SSH Key Authentication only.  (Bare minimum of security, at least)

After sitting about 9h in the Data Centre the last two days, we came in today, changed the '0 to an '2 and it worked instantly <3. Thank you guys a lot.
UFW and SSH Key only is of course already set :)
